# 3 <label> tags share one same rule but display differently

Tags: html, css

First, let's see my screenshot. It expresses my problem very detail:
[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRhLF.png)

Here is a small part from my code:

```css
.contain {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 min-width: 450px;
 padding: 0 50pt 10pt 50pt
}

.contain.layout-col {
 flex-direction: column
}

.item.field {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-bottom: 6pt;
 max-width: 650px;
 min-width: 300px
}

.item.field > label {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10pt 5pt 6pt 5pt;
 width: 50px
}

.item.field > input {
 padding: 10pt 16pt 6pt 16pt;
 transition: all 0.21s ease-in-out;
 width: 100%
}

.item.field > input:focus {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #F06292;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-bottom: -2px
}
```

```html
<div class='contain layout-col'>
  <div class='item field'>
    <label for='name' id='name-label'>Name</label>
    <input placeholder='What&#39;s your name?' id='name' type='text' name='name' required/>
  </div>
  <div class='item field'>
    <label for='email' id='email-label'>Email</label>
    <input placeholder='Do you have email?' id='email' type='email' name='email' required/>
  </div>
  <div class='item field'>
    <label for='number' id='number-label'>Age</label>
    <input placeholder='How old are you?' id='number' type='number' min='7' max='69' name='age' required/>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, 3 tags use one rule `.item.field > label`. And it all defines `width` as `50px` and label tag has been set to block element. At this time, it's expected to be 50px for width and the 3 of tags should be equal to each other. That is the idea, but only the 2 first tags follow the rule. The last one `#number-label` doesn't do so. It loses a few pixels!

I really have no idea how come it could be like that. I hope you guy could enlighten me. (I have other solution is using `float` property, but this bug is bugging me off so I very much want to understand about it.)

My code was write on CodePen.io and run test on both Chrome-69 and Firefox-62. The results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`width` does not work quite the same way when applied to flex items, especially when you have told the `input` to be 100% wide.

For a fixed width use `flex: 0 0 50px` instead.

```css
.contain {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 min-width: 450px;
 padding: 0 50pt 10pt 50pt
}

.contain.layout-col {
 flex-direction: column
}

.item.field {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-bottom: 6pt;
 max-width: 650px;
 min-width: 300px
}

.item.field > label {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10pt 5pt 6pt 5pt;
 flex: 0 0 50px
}

.item.field > input {
 padding: 10pt 16pt 6pt 16pt;
 transition: all 0.21s ease-in-out;
 /*width: 100% */
        /*try*/
        flex:1;
}

.item.field > input:focus {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #F06292;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-bottom: -2px
}
```

```html
<div class='contain layout-col'>
  <div class='item field'>
    <label for='name' id='name-label'>Name</label>
    <input placeholder='What&#39;s your name?' id='name' type='text' name='name' required/>
  </div>
  <div class='item field'>
    <label for='email' id='email-label'>Email</label>
    <input placeholder='Do you have email?' id='email' type='email' name='email' required/>
  </div>
  <div class='item field'>
    <label for='number' id='number-label'>Age</label>
    <input placeholder='How old are you?' id='number' type='number' min='7' max='69' name='age' required/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or we only add `flex-shrink:0` with the width to avoid the shrink effect